# Align Div in new row and and have same number of divs in a row

Tags: html, css

So i got the website looking default like this:

[Website default look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKU1U.png)

And when i change the width of the browser the rightest div gets aligned in the next row:

[Website smaller look false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCXqT.png)

But i want to the divs to be symmetrical and be the same number in one row like this:

[Website smaller look true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUK58.png)

Code is looking like this:

```
.interfacessection {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-content: left;
    }


    .interfaces{
      min-width: 130px;
      min-height: 100px;
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: rgb(40,40,50);
      border-radius: 17px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-color: rgb(150,150,160);
    }

    .interfaces div {
      margin: auto;
      align-self: center;
    }


<section class = "interfacessection">
        <div class = "interfaces buttons">
          <div class = "description buttons"> GPIO 12</div>
          <div class = "slider buttons" > <button  class = "ON"  id = "12" >ON</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class = "interfaces buttons">
          <div class = "description buttons"> GPIO 14</div>
          <div class = "slider buttons" > <button  class = "OFF"  id = "14">OFF</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class = "interfaces buttons">
          <div class = "description buttons"> GPIO 27</div>
          <div class = "slider buttons" > <button  class = "ON"  id = "27">ON</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class = "interfaces buttons">
          <div class = "description buttons"> GPIO 26</div>
          <div class = "slider buttons" ><button class = "ON" id = "26">ON</button></div>
        </div>
</section
```

I already tried to use
'''justify-content: space-around;'''

Comment: You need media queries to adjust this. Rows can't be split evenly like you require dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this much better with grid than with flex.
Like this:

```
.interfacessection {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-row-gap: 40px;
}
```

Then you can change display-template-columns with media querys.